# Reading multiple files in R

Tags: r

I have a directory full of different files. I want to read all '.xml' files from the directory and perform certain operations on each file and then want a single output dataframe.

I am able to get all the files from directory

```
files <- list.files(path="path",pattern = ".xml",full.names=TRUE)
read <- sapply(files, read.csv)
```

I have also done all the necessary operations on a single file.
I am getting the desired output for that file, but I am unaware of how to call each file and perform the same set of functions.

I want to read all the files one at a time and then perform a set of actions. 
My desired output should be a dataframe with corresponding file names & manipulated data.
Something like this...

```
Filename    data1   data2   data3   data4   data5
filename1      a       I       q       y    gg
filename1      b       j       r       z    hh
filename1      c       k       s       aa   ii
filename2      d       l       t       bb   jj
filename2      e       m       u       cc   kk
filename2      f       n       v       dd   ll
filename3      g       o       w       ee   mm
filename3      h       p       x       ff   nn
```

Comment: If you do `lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)`, it would be a `list` of data.frames. Without the maninpulation to do, it is difficult to comment.  suppose your function is `f1`, then loop through the `list` and do `lapply(lst1, f1)`

Comment: Or using tidyverse, `lst(as.list(files)) %>% imap_dfr(~ .x %>% mutate(....), .id = .y)`

Comment: As per the manipulation goes...it is about getting attribute values of certain nodes and then converging all of them into a dataframe-DF1. There will be one particular column having alphanumeric value which needs to be split as per certain rule and then stored into another data frame-DF2. DF1 and DF2 will be joined together to get DF as my output for that specific .xml file. Like the same needs to be performed for other .xml files present in the directory....i hope this makes things clear......

Comment: I once used the `rio` package for such purposes and made good experiences, you may want to take a look into `rio::import_list`.